# Arch Linux ARMv6 (RPi B+) boot issue

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I've asked around in the Raspberry Pi stack exchange, and am not having much luck, so I thought I'd try migrate this question here.

I am tinkering with different Linux flavours on the B+, but I am having trouble getting the latest ARMv6 Arch distribution up and going.

After following the standard installation steps at http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi, upon booting, I get the following:

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
```

This is then followed by the standard bourne shell prompt. No password prompt, no bash.

I have tried repeating the instructions. Same result.

I'm not accessing remotely using serial or SSH, just directly booting into the machine.

Any ideas?

Current partition scheme:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15.7 GB, 15719727104 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 479728 cylinders, total 30702592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbec0e908

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            2048      206847      102400    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          206848    30702591    15247872   83  Linux
```

Comment: Can you get yourself some log? either from `dmesq` or from `journalctl`

Comment: All I get is: `No journal files were found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is obviously wrong with the installation. Perhaps you're ignoring an important warning? Make a full console log of the installation process, adding `df` and `ls root` before `umount boot root`. Analize each warning you see, add warnings you don't understand to your post.

If there are no warnings during installation, check the output of `dmesg`, `mount`, `df` and `ls /etc /dev`  once you boot your system. You should see the root fs correctly mounted and expected files should be present on it.

Finally, find out what runlevel you're in with `runlevel` and try to switch to `runlevel 5`

Answer (score 0):

Checked all for all warnings, no issues. After the third try, got the magic login prompt!

Still not sure what the initial issue was, but I suspect it was something to do with a corrupt boot partition.